# Get datetime between start and end datetime

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Start_Date                           End_Date
2019-09-10 17:48:00.000        2019-09-10 18:00:00.000
2019-09-10 17:00:00.000        2019-09-10 17:45:00.000
2019-09-10 17:30:00.000        2019-09-10 18:00:00.000
2019-09-11 08:00:00.000        2019-09-11 09:30:00.000
2019-09-11 08:30:00.000        2019-09-11 09:30:00.000
2019-09-11 12:00:00.000        2019-09-11 13:00:00.000
2019-09-11 12:30:00.000        2019-09-11 13:15:00.000
2019-09-11 12:15:00.000        2019-09-11 13:15:00.000
```

If i pass Start_Date and End_Date in Query
for e.g Start_Date =  '2019-09-11 12:00.000' and End_Date='2019-09-11 13:15.000'

Expected Result:

```
Start_Date                        End_date
2019-09-11 12:00:00.000    2019-09-11 13:00:00.000
2019-09-11 12:30:00.000    2019-09-11 13:15:00.000
2019-09-11 12:15:00.000    2019-09-11 13:15:00.000
```

Comment: Please reverse your most recent edit and look at my edit. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) p.p.s. have you looked at `BETWEEN`?

Comment: Yes BETWEEN will give only  2019-09-11 12:00:00.000    2019-09-11 13:15:00.000

Comment: Not a SQL Server man but have you tried various permutations of `<`, `>` and `=`? Please provide data as DML `INSERT INTO...` or as a fiddle. Help us to help you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Full overlap:

```
SELECT * 
FROM source
WHERE Start_Date >= '2019-09-11 12:00.000' 
  AND End_Date <= '2019-09-11 13:15.000'
```

Partial overlap (not adjacent only, for adjacents replace strong unequiations `>` and `>` with safe ones `>=` and `<=`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM source
WHERE End_Date > '2019-09-11 12:00.000' 
  AND Start_Date < '2019-09-11 13:15.000'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2b6bb6577d3c665cbc28c245fc1d80a2)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Start_Date BETWEEN '2019-09-11 12:00.000' and '2019-09-11 13:15.000' AND End_Date BETWEEN '2019-09-11 12:00.000' and '2019-09-11 13:15.000'
```